# React is undefined after import

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

While trying to kickstart my app I'm getting that both React or ReactDOM are undefined.
This is when using the es2015 `import` syntax, preprocessed with babel.
Using the regular `require` it loads fine.
The snippet is like this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SearchForm from './utils/components.jsx';
$(function () {
    var form = $('#search-form');
    ReactDOM.render(<SearchForm />, form.get(0)); // react is undefined. raises InvariantViolation
})
```

Actual traceback reads like this:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

Which looks like a react error, but using a breakpoint in the offending line (before `ReactDOM`) and trying to evaluate both `React` or `ReactDOM` it returns `undefined`, it's not the same for $ or any other import in the same module.

What gives?

Comment: It's probably undefined in the console due to sourcemaps not translating the name correctly. What's the content of "./utils/components.jsx"? Seems like it doesn't export a component.

Comment: Check whether you export default the component is components.jsx. Since you name the file components.jsx I assume you have multiple components in the file. If that's the case export each component and import it with import { SearchForm } from './utils/components.jsx'. Check ES6 syntax that's what you're using.

Comment: isn't `import foo from 'bar'` the same as `import { foo } from 'bar'`. I'm export `SearchForm` like:

     module.exports = {
        SearchForm,
    }

But it's not being imported, same than React...

Comment: Is `SearchForm` really a `.jsx` file and not `.js`?

Comment: @tutuca no those two statements are not the same. `import foo` without the braces expects `export default` on the other side. `module.exports = { foo }` on the other hand can be consumed with `import { foo }`

Comment: @Chris, both are preprocessed by babel with the same directive.

Comment: @azium: ohhhh. Good to know... brb, be checking all my exports :)

Comment: Can you show the code for this `SearchForm` component?

Comment: @Chris: this is the definition of [SearchForm](http://dpaste.com/2FP5EKN)

Comment: @Chris.. If you put that on an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: lol... Reading again I think I should've mention @azium....